# How to delete mongodb document with two conditions one with $gt operator?

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to retrieve the following information:

```
delete from database where name = 'AAA' and age>20;
```

but for MongoDB in Java. Essentially, it should delete the document that contain the word `AAA` and age greater than 20 in them. I know that there is the `$in` operator in MongoDB, but how do I do the same in Java, using the Java driver? I've been trying to look for it everywhere but am getting nothing. I've tried:

```
query = new BasicDBObject("age", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "20"), new BasicDBObject("name", "AAA"));
```

JSON which i want to delete is like this.

```
{"school" : "NewSchool" , "name" : "AAA" , "age" : "50"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the find-term:

```
{
   "name" : "AAA",
   "age" : { $gt : 20 }
}
```

Construct this as your basic DB object, or simply use the new 3.x Filters to create the Bson for you. (As I personally only use 3.x, here's the appropriate example):

```
MongoClient client = ...
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(...);
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(...);
coll.deleteMany(Filters.and(Filters.eq("name", "AAA"), Filters.gt("age", 20)));
```